# Laravel 5.5 HasManyThrough Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have the following database:

```
teams
-----
id
user_id


users
-----
id


pages
-----
id
user_id
team_id -> (nullable)
```

So a User can create a Team, and create a Page

Currently, I have the following relationships setup (replace with `$this`)

```
teams_owned() -> $user->hasMany(Team::class);        // Teams a user owns
pages()       -> $user->hasMany(Page::class);        // Page a user created 
user()        -> $team->belongsTo(User::class);      // User who created team
user()        -> $page->belongsTo(User::class);      // User who created the Page
```

However, a User can join a team by creating a Page for that team. In this case the `pages` table will fill in the `team_id`. Where a page is created and is not for a team, the `team_id` value will be `null`

I wanted to add a relationship for `User` to get the `Team`s joined. As explained above, you are part of `Team` if you have created a `Page` for it.

I have tried the following:

```
public function teams_joined()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Team::class, FundraisingPage::class);
}
```

I'm not sure if I should be using a `HasManyThrough` in this situation

As a backup I have the following:

```
public function teams_joined()
{
    $uniqueTeamIds = $this->pages()->onlyForTeams()->get()->pluck('id')->unique();
    return Team::whereIn('id', $uniqueTeamIds)->get();
}
```

where `onlyForTeams()` is defined on `Page` as

```
public function scopeOnlyForTeams($query) {
    return $query->whereNotNull('team_id');
}
```

But I wanted to use a proper relationship so was wondering if I should be using `HasManyThrough` or something else for this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `BelongsToMany` relationship:

```
public function teams_joined()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'pages');
}
```